# Rotate image and adjust size of div new image rotate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, rotation

I try rotate horizontal image and show in vertical but i want do this, the size of div don´t change when rotate image inside

**This it´s my code :**

https://jsfiddle.net/3b9yhdj6/2/

**SIMPLE CSS FOR CONTAINER IMAGE**

```
#content
{
float:left;
position:relative;
min-width:10%;
max-height:350px;
border:1px solid;
overflow:hidden;
}


</style>
```

**LITTLE JQUERY CODE**

```
<script>
function rotation()
{

var w=jQuery(".image_rotate").height();
var h=jQuery(".image_rotate").width();

jQuery('#content').css("width",""+h+"px");
jQuery('#content').css("height",""+w+"px");

jQuery('.image_rotate').css({"transform": "rotate(90deg)"});

}
</script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="content">
<img src="http://www.cuantos.net/wp-content/uploads/Cuantos-ejes-de-simetria-tiene-un-rectangulo1.png" class="image_rotate" />
</div>

<div onclick="rotation();">Rotate Now</div>
```

My problem it´s , never get the div container , adjust the size when rotate image , i try all but never get this finally , i try put example for test

**Thank´s , regards**

Answer (score 1):

First, you've switched `h` and `w` twice. `h` should be height and `w`, width.

Then, it's best to use `transform-origin:0 0;` to know you're rotating around the upper left corner. Then you'll need to offset the object by 100% to the right using `margin-left: 100%`

### [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3b9yhdj6/3/)

```
function rotation()
{
var h = jQuery(".image_rotate").height();
var w = jQuery(".image_rotate").width();

jQuery('#content').css("width",h+"px");
jQuery('#content').css("height",w+"px");

jQuery('.image_rotate').css({"transform": "rotate(90deg)", "margin-left":"100%"});
}
```